# Angular 6, ServiceWorker ios Safari and Video element byte-range requests

Tags: angular, angular6

ServiceWorker on IOS 12 Safari is not working with HTML5 Video element. I just get a blank screen, the devices camera does not stream into view. I'm using the video element for screen capture. It works fine on Android.

I suspect this could be the issue?

HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback. (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support byte-range requests.

I tried adding:

```
// rtc peer connection patch
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
// getUserMedia patch
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media';
```

to polyfill.ts, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a different (but perhaps related) issue with audio in Safari as a result of the Angular ServiceWorker (SW) failing range requests.

To fix the issue I patched the `ngsw-worker.js` file in the `@angular/service-worker` package to have the SW ignore range requests.

I found the suggested fix here: [Service worker doesn't support seeking in videos #25865](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25865#issuecomment-443187935)

I hope this helps.